# outlook command won't return prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-outlook, batch, prompt

So I'm writing a cmd script so I can open some programs on a double click. It looks like this:

```
:: Open Logbook
code "\\wsl$\path\to\the\logbook" | exit 0

:: Open Firefox
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" ^
    "https://site1.com/", ^
    "https://site2", ^
    "..."
    
:: Open console
"C:\Program Files\cmder\Cmder.exe"

:: Open Teams
"C:\Users\62000670\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe" --processStart "Teams.exe"

:: Open Outlook
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
echo "All done!"
exit 0
```

What I noticed is that the **Outlook command** (unlike all the other commands) **is not returning the prompt**. As a consequence, the rest of the script won't run (that is why Outlook is the last on the list), and [the terminal window is kept open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WnRH.png).

Is there a way to have the script to continue after Outlook has started?

### What I've tried so far:

1. Tried to create an expression that would evaluate if Outlook succeded/failed to start

   - `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" | exit 0"` --> same issue
   - `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" && echo "Guive it back Outlook!"` --> same issue
2. Looked for [Outlook Flags](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Outlook):

   - `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle` --> same issue
   - `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /embeded` --> didn't even start (as one might have expected!...)

---

edited from here on

### Perfectly Suitable Workaround

Using the [start command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) (thank you [S. Brottes](https://superuser.com/users/964984/s-brottes))

```
start "Some Title" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
```

Note that the *"Some Title"* part could have been omitted if the actual command didn't need quoting.

### Nitpicking

Is there a way to do this without resorting to an external command?
What is the fundamental difference from this particular command to the previous ones?

Comment: Could you try with the `start` command ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks!
Took me a while to realize that my cammand was being passed as a title because it needs to be quoted but `start " " "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"` worked just fine.

Comment: still.... shouldn't there be a way to have the program return the prompt to the shell it is running on?  I mean, the `start` is managing to do that somehow...

Comment: Update your question with the updated code that uses start using proper syntax